# Will many files affect the performance of the app?

Tags: ios

I am creating an iOS app and it will contain LARGE amount of files, I mean thousands.

The size is small, but they are too many.

I am confused which is better, to bundle them directly inside the app, or zip them inside one file and extract it to documents on first run of the app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS? How will the files be used? What performance issues are you worrying about?

Comment: iOS app with webview and many web applications such as phpMyAdmin, elFinder, Composer extracted (not phar), the total files more than 2000. I am concerned if this will affect the speed on startup and reading files.

Comment: @Porizm I'm concerned about what you're trying to do here. Running PHP applications in an iOS app seems really questionable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***(It is a bit unclear what your setup is or what are the issues you fear (as @rmaddy pointed out in the comments. But here are my two cents on bundling too many files in one app, for what it's worth:)***

Back in the days of iOS 4, I had an issue trying to bundle around 400 PNGs in an iOS app. At runtime, some of the files weren't available and the app was very slow.

When you add resource files **as "Group"** (i.e., **yellow folder icons**) to an Xcode project, they all get copied at the root directory of the app bundle, regardless of what folder substructure the groups may have in Xcode's "Project Navigator" pane.
They are accessible at runtime like so:

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MyFile", ofType: "png")
```

#### The Problem

The problem seems to be that, at least back then, iOS would chuckle if there were too many files at the top level of one directory. Because when using the "Groups" option (yellow folder icon) everything ends up at the root regardless, there is no way out.

---

#### The Solution

If you instead use the **"As Folder References"** option (**blue folder icons**), whatever directory structure you have in your Mac gets preserved within the built app bundle. This way, you can split your files into subdirectories containing (say) no more than 50 files each, and you're set.

The only catch is, that you need to specify the subdirectory when you read the path, using something like:

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MyFile", ofType: "png", inDirectory: "Images/01-50/")
```

Also, if your files are images (like in my case), you can no longer use:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "MyFile")
```

You need to use:

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MyFile", ofType: "png", inDirectory: "Images/01-50/")
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)
```

*(I'm not sure how asset catalogs, which are compiled, fair in this respect since I haven't faced this scenario since they were introduced, but asset catalogs do offer the option of organizing your assets into subfolders...)*

---

**Addendum:** As they say, premature optimization is not good, so at the end of the day you should at least **try** the simpler, easier option of just bundling the files once, and test/profile it.

Unnecessary complexity is more lines of code and therefore more potential bugs, it may eventually come back and bite you.